# Jquery 'on change' eventhandler is making multiple unexpected ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm creating a form where an AJAX call is made after two inputs are selected (a company value and a date value), and the returned data populates the choices available for input selections in a table.

Here is my code:

```
var _cateringCo = $('#catering-company-id')
var _orderDate = $("#order_date")

    $("#order_date, #catering-company-id").on('change', function(){

          // clear out all products in table first
          $('#sample_order_products tr').remove()

          //only make call if both fields do not have null values
          if(_cateringCo.val() !== "" && _orderDate.val() !== ""){

            var data = {catering_company_id: _cateringCo.val(), order_date: _orderDate.val()};

            $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              data: data,
              url: '<%= get_main_products_for_day_admin_sample_orders_path%>',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){
                var products = data.products

                //append new input item to table
                if(products.length > 0){
                  $('#sample_order_products').append(addProducts(products));
                }

              }
            })

          }
```

Here are the other two methods used to populate the table after the callback is completed:

```
var addOptions = function(products){
      string = "";
      for (var i = 0; products.length > i; i++){
        var product = products[i]
        var name = product.display_name
        var product_id = product.product_id

        string += "<option value='"+product_id+"'>"+name+"</option>"
      }
      return string
    }

    var addProducts = function(products){
      return "<tr>" +
                "<td>" +
                  "<select name='sample_order[sample_order_meals_attributes][][product_id]' class='validate[required]'>" + addOptions(products) +
                "</td>" +
                "<td>" +
                  "<input name='sample_order[sample_order_meals_attributes][][quantity]' type='number' class='validate[required]'>" +
                "</td>"
              "</tr>"
    }
```

My problem is that **when I make a change event (selecting a new date from datepicker) for the 'date' value, I'm making 3 calls** (which ends up appending 3 rows to my table).

However, **when I make a change event for the 'company' value, it's only making one call**, and thus appending 1 row to the table (which is what I want).

I have no idea what's different about the change event for the date that is doing this.

Comment: are you using datepicker from jQuery UI?

Comment: Yea I am using the jquery datepicker. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: could be, try unbind the `change` handler on `#order_date`, and use `datepicker`'s `onSelect` handler instead.  http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect